# JQuery - How do I capture the opening and closing tag of the selected element?

Tags: jquery

Say I have something similar to this:

```
<div class="myawesomeclass" id="myTag"><strong>Lots of stuff</strong></div>
```

Ideally I would like to end up with two variables with the string values for the opening and closing tags:

OpeningTag : 
CloseingTag :

How can I do this with JQuery?

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?  There is probably a better way than what you're attempting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use javascripts `outerHTML` property to get the HTML of your tag then split it using the inner HTML as the separator, here's an example:

```js
var tag = $('#myTag'),
  outerHTML = tag[0].outerHTML,
  innerHTML = tag.html(),
  result = outerHTML.split(innerHTML),
  openingTag = result[0],
  closingTag = result[1];

$('.oT').text(openingTag);
$('.cT').text(closingTag);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myawesomeclass" id="myTag"><strong>Lots of stuff</strong>
</div>

<div class="result">
  opening Tag: <span class="oT"></span><br>
  closing Tag: <span class="cT"></span>
</div>
```